# How to display list of countries as webpage in expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I am beginner with react native expo, just creating my first project. I am able to make a flat list and app is working great so far.

However now I need to make something like this,

[image]

As being newbie, I am not sure where to start, It seems like a webview is used but I am not sure how to put flatview into webview, or am I completely on wrong track ?

This is what I coded so far,

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Clicking on each button will navigate to a specific link I will add to each button

Answer (score 1):

**Result:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import React from "react";
import { FlatList, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      { id: "00", name: "Mazda RX-7" },
      { id: "01", name: "McLaren F1" },
      { id: "02", name: "Mini Cooper" },
      { id: "03", name: "BMW 645 Ci" }
    ]
  };
  render() {
    const columns = 3;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <FlatList
          data={createRows(this.state.data, columns)}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          numColumns={columns}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            if (item.empty) {
              return <View style={[styles.item, styles.itemEmpty]} />;
            }
            return (
              <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name}</Text>
              </View>
            );
          }}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

function createRows(data, columns) {
  const rows = Math.floor(data.length / columns);
  let lastRowElements = data.length - rows * columns;

  while (lastRowElements !== columns) {
    data.push({
      id: `empty-${lastRowElements}`,
      name: `empty-${lastRowElements}`,
      empty: true
    });
    lastRowElements += 1;
  }

  return data;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#dcda48",
    flexBasis: 0,
    flexGrow: 1,
    margin: 4,
    padding: 20
  },
  itemEmpty: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  },
  text: {
    color: "#333333"
  }
});

export default App;
```